# Get most repetitive item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'];
```

How can I get the most popular from array?

```
arr.getPopular() // 'a'
```

Can someone explain me how to achive this?
I've tried to convert to object http://jsbin.com/repokasati/edit?html,js,console,output and have something like

```
var obj = {
  a: 3,
  b: 1,
  c: 0,
  d: 0
}
```

How can I get key with biggest value from obj?

Comment: iterate through the array, save `popularItem` and a `popularItemCount` variables and replace them if you get any larger values.

Comment: @h2ooooooo, sort on object?

Comment: The most repetive element in array

Comment: @NinaScholz Yeah, ignore that completely - I'm currently working on a flash project and mistakenly thought of `Array.sortOn` (which doesn't even work on an object, it works on an *array of objects*).

Comment: @h2ooooooo what do you mean?

Comment: I agree with @h2ooooooo. There may be a library that has a function that does it all for you, but at the base level, you should create a second list that holds the count for each occurrence, and then look for the highest number in that count list.

Comment: @Hiero Use a `for` loop to guide through your `obj` object - before you do this you define `var popularItem, popularItemCount = 0` then while you loop through it, you simply check `if (itemCount > popularItemCount) { popularItem = item; popularItemCount = itemCount; }`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It returns equal references, too:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    count = function (array) {
        var o = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a] = (o[a] || 0) + 1;
        });
        return o;
    }(arr),
    max = function (o) {
        var keys = Object.keys(o);
        return keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
            if (o[k] > o[r[0]]) {
                return [k];
            }
            if (o[k] === o[r[0]]) {
                r.push(k);
            }
            return r;
        }, [keys.shift()]);
    }(count);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(count, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(max, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Like the way you initialize and increment the counter in a single line: (o[a] || 0) + 1.  up vote.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery $.each function to iterate through the key and value pair  and get the key having the highest value .Below is the code for the same

```
 var obj = {
  a: 3,
   b: 1,
   c: 0,
   d: 0
  }
 var base=0;
 $.each(obj,function(key,value)
{ 
{
 if(value>base)
 high=key;
 base=value;
 }});
  console.log(high);
```

high will give the value of the key having the highest value